# call method for mysql connection from main in java

Tags: java, mysql

im learning java, i added the mysql connector with netbeans and im trying to do a sample app to query a database, however i dont know how to call the method that makes the connection from the main method.

here is my code:

MySqlJdbcTest.java:

```
public class MySqlJdbcTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
    //          new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            String connectionUser = "root";
            String connectionPassword = "";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM java");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("name");
                String lastName = rs.getString("number");
                System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", First Name: " + firstName
                        + ", Last Name: " + lastName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the test.java file:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySqlJdbcTest prueba = new MySqlJdbcTest();
        prueba();
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename your "main" method to something else, like "DoTest", then in Test.main, call prueba.DoTest();

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `main(String[])` methods. Java requires that you have one of these as the entry point to your application.

If we assume that `Test.main()` is the entry point for your application, you can call the other as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MySqlJdbcTest.main(args);
}
```

which is equivalent to calling a `static` method.

However, to make things more clear, I suggest you rename the `MySqlJdbcTest.main()` method to something else and possibly remove the `static` modifier and the `String[]` parameter. It would end up as something like

```
public class MySqlJdbcTest {
    public void executeSql() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
    //          new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        //conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
            String connectionUser = "root";
            String connectionPassword = "";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM java");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString("id");
                String firstName = rs.getString("name");
                String lastName = rs.getString("number");
                System.out.println("ID: " + id + ", First Name: " + firstName
                        + ", Last Name: " + lastName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Because the method is now an instance method, you need an instance of the class to run it on

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySqlJdbcTest prueba = new MySqlJdbcTest();
        prueba.executeSql();
    }
}
```

Consider reading through the [official Java tutorials, here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)